How to use transformers library for fine-tuning
I wrote a code to fine-tune using the transformers library of hugging face. However, the model raise the following errors while training. I think it's a problem that the value was delivered to List type, so I think I need to modify the last value part of the compute_metrics function to list, but I don't know what to do. It's my first time using this library, so I'd appreciate it if you could solve this error.
[Code]
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import evaluate
from transformers import AutoImageProcessor

checkpoint = 'nvidia/mit-b0'
img_processor = AutoImageProcessor.from_pretrained(checkpoint, reduce_labels=True)
from torchvision.transforms import ColorJitter

jitter = ColorJitter(brightness=.25, contrast=.25, saturation=.25, hue=.1)

def train_transforms(exmaple_batch):
    imgs = [jitter(x) for x in exmaple_batch['image']]
    labels = [x for x in exmaple_batch['annotation']]
    inputs = img_processor(imgs, labels)

    return inputs

def val_transforms(example_batch):
    imgs = [x for x in example_batch['image']]
    labels = [x for x in example_batch['annotation']]
    inputs = img_processor(imgs, labels)

    return inputs

train_dataset.set_transform(train_transforms)
test_dataset.set_transform(val_transforms)

metric = evaluate.load('mean_iou')

def compute_metrics(eval_pred):
    with torch.no_grad():
        logits, labels = eval_pred
        logits_tensor = torch.from_numpy(logits)
        logits_tensor = nn.functional.interpolate(
            logits_tensor,
            size=labels.shape[-2:],
            mode='bilinear',
            align_corners=False,
        ).argmax(dim=1)
        
        pred_labels = logits_tensor.detach().cpu().numpy()
        metrics = metric.compute(
            predictions=pred_labels,
            references=labels,
            num_labels=n_labels,
            ignore_index=255,
            reduce_labels=False
        )
        
        for k, v in metrics.items():
            if isinstance(v, np.ndarray):
                metrics[k] = v.tolist()
        
        return metrics

from transformers import AutoModelForSemanticSegmentation, TrainingArguments, Trainer

model = AutoModelForSemanticSegmentation.from_pretrained(checkpoint, id2label=id2label, label2id=label2id)
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir='segformer-b0-scene-parse-150',
    learning_rate=6e-5,
    num_train_epochs=50,
    per_device_train_batch_size=8,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=8,
    save_total_limit=5,
    evaluation_strategy='steps',
    save_strategy='steps',
    save_steps=20,
    eval_steps=20,
    logging_steps=1,
    eval_accumulation_steps=5,
    remove_unused_columns=False,
)
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=test_dataset,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
)

trainer.train()

[Error Message]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[46], line 25
      1 training_args = TrainingArguments(
      2     output_dir='segformer-b0-scene-parse-150',
      3     learning_rate=6e-5,
   (...)
     14     remove_unused_columns=False,
     15 )
     17 trainer = Trainer(
     18     model=model,
     19     args=training_args,
   (...)
     22     compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
     23 )
---> 25 trainer.train()

File ~/anaconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:1780, in Trainer.train(self, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval, **kwargs)
   1778         hf_hub_utils.enable_progress_bars()
   1779 else:
-> 1780     return inner_training_loop(
   1781         args=args,
   1782         resume_from_checkpoint=resume_from_checkpoint,
   1783         trial=trial,
   1784         ignore_keys_for_eval=ignore_keys_for_eval,
...
    163     "Invalid image type. Expected either PIL.Image.Image, numpy.ndarray, torch.Tensor, tf.Tensor or "
    164     f"jax.ndarray, but got {type(images)}."
    165 )

ValueError: Invalid image type. Expected either PIL.Image.Image, numpy.ndarray, torch.Tensor, tf.Tensor or jax.ndarray, but got <class 'list'>.

